# Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 2 (Boo)

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, boo

I installed [this](https://github.com/Shammah/boo-sublime) through Package Control in ST2. However, when I am coding in a .boo file, it doesn't use the syntax highlighting (although it did find booc.exe, I can select it as a Build option and it compiles). I am new to the program so I've had difficulty fixing the issue on my own, and I haven't found anything to help me online. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a `.boo` file, and select `View -> Syntax -> Boo` to enable highlighting for that particular file. The list of languages is also available from the menu on the far right of the status bar at the bottom of the Sublime window. To enable this language for every time you open a Boo file, select `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Boo` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for such a basic question. I have one more question and I would be grateful if you can answer it: is it possible to have ST2 run booi.exe instead of booc.exe so that I can have it compiled and interpreted? Or must I find a heavier IDE / run booi from the command line?

Comment: @ModestVillain Yes it is. Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open the `Packages` folder. Go to the `Boo` directory and open `Boo.sublime-build` in Sublime. You can edit the first line to change the executable called, as well as the command-line options.

Comment: Thank you again, you've been very helpful. Everything is working as I need it.